# Change an element css while hovering on another element in css?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to change an element's css while focusing or hovering on one of it's children?

Ex: while I move my mouse on A, B's background color changes.
if B is a descendant A, it is possible.

--A
-----B

using `#A:hover #B { background-color: blue }`

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/lpaHB)**

---

in sibling:

---A
---B

It is : `#A:hover ~ #B { background-color: blue; }`

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KJDhy)**

---

assume B is a descendant of A.
**what if I want to change #A background, while I am hovering on B. how could it be?**

--A
-----B

Comment: You seem to be looking for a parent selector. If that is the case, it is not possible atleast until CSS4 comes.

Comment: ..And until then, Javascript is your best alternative.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change element style on hover another element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966180/change-element-style-on-hover-another-element)

Comment: and [How to change one element while hovering over another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614423/how-to-change-one-element-while-hovering-over-another?rq=1)

Comment: @Liam I mean parent. your link is not about parent selector.

Comment: @aliA: Are you looking only for *whether it is possible with pure CSS* or *are you looking for a solution (JS/jQuery based)*?

Comment: Why not use JS? That's what it was designed for.

Comment: I just wanted to know it is possible or not. may be I use js for this.

Comment: @aliA: Ok, no issues :) I think there are already quite a few JS/jQuery based solutions in SO for the same topic if in case you need them :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing this in pure CSS is unfortunately not possible...at this time. However, there is supposedly an upcoming *parent selector* that would work well in this scenario. Click [here](http://www.red-team-design.com/css-parent-selector) for more info.

### Work-around

In the meantime, you can also use javascript and/or jquery to accomplish this pretty easily.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/B5JDL/)

HTML

```
<div id="div1">
  div 1 area
  <p id="paragraph">
    This is paragraph
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
  border:1px solid lightgray;
}
p {
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  padding: 8px;
}

.altbg {
    background:grey;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('#paragraph').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('altbg')
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('altbg')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It is actually possible in css.
Somebody made this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/u7tYE/

```css
#a:hover + #b {
        display:block;
        background-color:rgb(200,200,150);
    }
    #b{display:none;background-color:rgb(200,200,150;}
```

```html
<a id="a">Menu</a>
<div id="b">
<p>Home</p>
<p>About</p>
<p>Login</p>
</div>
```

It works perfectly.