# How do I change the color of a nav link when on a certain ID selector? More specifically, using Parallax script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So let's say I'm scrolling down using the Parallax effect.
Different sections have different ID's
There's the intro, body, disclaimer, whatever ID's.
I set up a Nav bar at the top where it scrolls to whatever ID you want on the page. Simple stuff

but let's say I'm on the disclaimer section(using #disclaimer id)
How do I make the nav link a different color (on thenav bar)when the viewer is on said ID?

Help is much appreciated. Thanks!:)

Comment: possible, show me the HTML code or any fiddle.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966180/change-element-style-on-hover-another-element

Answer (score 0):

i may not have a solution for you. But did you check out the Affix from Bootstrap?
It does work like you want your navigation-bar to work and maybe [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix) will help you.

I would recommend to customize your download so you just download the affix-script and try to understand it.

Hope that this one will help. :)

greetings